# Loop the dataframe to create igraph

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, graph

I have a data frame, which is an edge list for R/igraph:

```
node_one node_two weight group
 1        2       1     175221    
 3        4       1     175221
 5        6       1     175221
 7        8       1     175221
 9        10      1     576546
 11       12      2     576546
 13       14      2     576546
 15       16      2     789535
 17       18      2     789535
 19       20      2     789535
```

I want to loop through df according to the different value of hee_provn1, create multiple graphs and get graph measures.

My code is here:

```
# Install packages
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

df <- data.frame(node_one=seq(1,19,2),
                 node_two=seq(2,20,2),
                 weight = c(rep(2,5),rep(2,5)),
                 group=c(rep(175221,4),rep(576546,3),rep(789535,3)))

final.df1 <- c()
for(x in unique(df$group)){
  df2 <- subset(df, subset = group == x)

  # Create the graph 
  G <- graph_from_data_frame(df2, directed=FALSE)

  d = degree(G)   # The number of vertex's adjacent edges
  c = closeness(G, weight = df2$weight)                             # Measures how many steps is required to access every other vertex from a given vertex
  b = betweenness(G, weight = df2$weight)                           # Defined by the number of geodesics (shortest paths) going through a vertex or an edge
  result <- data.frame(x, d,c,b)             


  final.df1 <- rbind(final.df1, result)
}

colnames(final.df1) <- c('group','degree','closeness','betweeness')
```

The head of final result is like

```
   group degree closeness betweeness
1 175221      1      0.02          0
3 175221      1      0.02          0
5 175221      1      0.02          0
7 175221      1      0.02          0
2 175221      1      0.02          0
4 175221      1      0.02          0
```

However, I found growing things dynamically in a loop is inefficient and slow in R. I am new to R, just found there's dyplr or tidyverse to use. But its hard for me, especially I don't know how to handle the weight column.

My try is here:

```
final <- df %>%
       group_by(group) %>%     
       nest() %>%                   
       mutate(data=map(data,~c(apply(.x,1,c)))) %>%  
       mutate(data=map(data,~graph(.x,directed=F))) %>%
```

Please show me how to finish this?

Comment: I had posted an answer using `split/lapply` but then I've benchmarked it and your `for/unique` is 26% faster so I deleted it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.